# SPARQL query to identify broader shortcuts

Tags: sparql

I am doing a SPARQL query on broader concepts. I have top concept say with an id 37003. There are concepts 37001 having broader relation to 37002 & 37003 and another concept 37002 having broader relation to 37003

37001 < 37002

37001 < 37003

37002 < 37003

here < denotes broader relation

I tried with the below query:

```
SELECT ?concept ?broader WHERE {
?concept rdf:type skos:Concept;
skos:broader+ ?broader.
} ORDER BY ?concept
```

which results in

37001 < 37002

37001 < 37003

37002 < 37003

Is it possible to construct two sparql queries resulting in

37001 < 37002 < 37003 and 37001 < 37003

Please help me!

Comment: that is hard to do because you are trying to inference data which can not be done by using a SPARQL query.

Comment: Thanks @Rotan075 for your views. Is there a way to resolve, I do have the XML version of the RDF. Additional thoughts will help me a lot!

Comment: Wait! What happens if you use: `skos:broaderTransitive` instead of `skos:broader`?

Comment: He wants to compute all paths between root and leaf nodes!